# Emmet - Sublime Text 3 - Multiple Custom Text

Tags: sublimetext3, emmet

I was wondering if Emmet had a function to add multiple custom text when creating multiple elements.

Here's an example of what I'd like to achieve. If I type some sort of command like that:

```
li{This is first li / This is second li}*2
```

I Would like to get:

```
<li> This is first li </li>
<li> This is secondli </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are already typing custom text you can use [Wrap with Abbreviation](http://docs.emmet.io/actions/wrap-with-abbreviation) Ctrl+Shift+G on Windows
eg.

You've got your custom list separated by new lines

```
This is first li 
This is second li
```

Now select all of this and use wrap with abbreviation and type `li*` in the input to wrap all elements in `li` tag

You can also wrap all of it into `ul` / `ol` by typing `ul>li*` / `ol>li*`